# Don't see data, which was exported from Firebase to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, export, firebase-analytics

I have exported analytics data from firebase to big query. 
But I don't see events from some of app version.

These versions are in release, but they are available only to me, not for all users.
I see the data in Firebase report, but not in BigQuery.

Could you please help me to understand, why I don't see the data from some app versions? 
What are the conditions of data export?

Comment: For debugging, please use the BigQuery issue tracker. Please add any project ids that can help identify your project and issues. There's not much we can do here if you don't add more specifics.